# Finding the determinant of anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

How would one find the determinant of an anti-diagonal matrix ($n \times n$), without using eigenvalues and/or traces (those I haven't learned yet):

My initial idea was to swap the first and n-th row, then the second and $n-1$-th row and so on, until I get a diagonal determinant, however how many swaps do I have to perform for that to happen? (Note: I do know the sign changes so I'll have $-1$ to some power times the now diagonal determinant, the problem is to find to what power).

For example: $\left| \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & n-1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & n-1 & 0 \\
\vdots \\
0 & n-1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
n-1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0
\end{matrix} \right|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. If $n$ is even, you will need $\frac{n}{2}$ swap operations

$$ n \leftrightarrow 1, (n-1) \leftrightarrow 2, \ldots, \frac{n}{2}+1 \leftrightarrow \frac{n}{2}. $$

If $n$ is odd, you will need $\frac{n-1}{2}$ swap operations. Try to check that this works for small values of $n$.

Comment: That I kinda figured out for small values of n, but then what would be the solution for that example given above, since I don't know if n is even or odd.

Comment: You can divide it into two cases and write what happens if $n$ is even and what happens if $n$ is odd. This is ok - after all, the answer does depend on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: My teacher wrote it like $ \left(-1\right)^{\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}} $ my guess was because 1/2 of the elements are even and 1/2 are odd.. yet still not 100% sure how she got that.

Comment: It's just a fancy way of writing the determinant as $(n-1)^n (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ instead of $\begin{cases} (n-1)^n(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}} & n \text{ is even} \\ (n-1)^n(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} & n \text { is odd}. \end{cases}$.

Comment: But both ways are correct. To see why it is the same, note that if $n$ is even then $n - 1$ is odd and so $(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}} = \left( (-1)^{\frac{n}{2}} \right)^{n-1} = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ and that if $n$ is odd then $n - 1$ is even and so $(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} = \left( (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \right)^{n} = (-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ so in both cases, the sign is equal to $(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$.

Comment: Another way to see this number of swaps is to note that we have a worst-case scenario bubble sort. The rows are in reverse order, requiring $(n - 1) + (n - 2) + \cdots + 1 = \cfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ swaps to get the diagonal matrix. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245018/bubble-sorting-question) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The number of swaps is clearly $\;\biggl\lfloor\dfrac n2\biggr\rfloor$.